# Objective-C custom UITableView class doesn't load

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In XCode 5 I startet with the Tab-Bar example and added a UITableView to my ViewController in storyboard. I'd like to use a custom class for that UITableView, so I added a new class to my project and set the class of my UITableView to be that new class in storyboard. I also set the cellIdentifier. The problem is that the app is still using the default UITableView class.
Could you please tell me what I'm missing?

Here is my custom UITableView class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@end

@implementation CustomTableView

- (CustomTableView*) init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self reloadData];
  }
  return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return 20;
}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return @"header title";
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString* staticCellIdentifier = @"customIdentifier";
  UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:staticCellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:staticCellIdentifier];
  }
  cell.textLabel.text = @"cellTitle";
  return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder? You have to set the custom class in there, too.

Comment: Thats what I meant by "set the class of my UITableView to be that new class in storyboard". Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `initWithCoder:` which is the designated initializer interface builder uses.

Something like this:

```
- (CustomTableView*) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
  self = [super initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder];
  if (self) {
    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self reloadData];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: I changed that and replaced my init method to be 'initWithCoder' but that didn't help. I still have a tableView with zero cells instead of 20.

Comment: The other thing is that you are calling `reloadData` in the initializer. Are you calling it anywhere else? Try adding it in the `viewDidAppear:` method.

Comment: Something else is wrong with your code. I created a brand new project and pasted in what you have here and it works fine. Here is a link to the project I made: http://cl.ly/3J0Z3j3k2f0o/download/Table.zip

Comment: Damn it, I had a typo in my class name. Your answer was correct. Thanks a lot!